# Не удается импортировать библиотеку из npm

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, frontend, cookie, npm

Для работы с куками я установил через npm библиотеку cookielib. После запуска этого кода:

```js
import {setCookie} from 'cookielib';
setCookie('name', 'value');
```

возникает ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: cookielib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.setCookie is not a function`. Для сборки я использую webpack, с импортом других библиотек проблем не возникает.
Также я пробовал импортировать через `require()` и указывать полный относительный путь к файлу библиотеки, но это не решило проблему.

upd: в файле библиотеки функции экспортируются следующим образом:

```js
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' &&
  process.versions != null &&
  process.versions.node != null) {
  global.document = {
    cookie: ''
  };
  module.exports = {
    document: document,
    setCookie: setCookie,
    getCookie: getCookie,
    deleteCookie: deleteCookie,
  }
}
```

Если убрать этот блок и дописать `export` перед объявлениями каждой функции, то их удается импортировать без ошибок при помощи `import {setCookie} from 'path';`. Но это не решает проблему, вносить изменения в исходники библиотеки я не хочу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099150/webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-function подойдет?

Comment: @Leviathan_ZC нет, исхожу из того, что в файл библиотеки правки вносить нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условие экспорта подразумевает процесс - серверное исполнение (NodeJS)

```
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' &&
  process.versions != null &&
  process.versions.node != null)
```

т.е. тут `условный экспорт` по этой причине лучше воспользоваться `CDN` по документации:

```
<!-- Main version -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cookielib/src/cookie.js"></script>
```

или

```
<!-- Minified version -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cookielib/src/cookie.min.js"></script>
```

В случае если не хочется постоянно дергать `CDN` можно сохранить ее локально и подключать так же через скрипт (опять же по документации)

```
<script src="../path/to/your/scripts/folder/cookie.min.js"></script>
```